# Tic Tac Toe Algorithm Glitch

Tags: java, android, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I am developing a Tic Tac Toe game in Android Studio and at the moment I have been able to sort most of the algorithm but I'm coming to a glitch I can't solve.

I have made the computer understand that it needs to take the middle cell if the human player starts in one of the corners but when I try to do the opposite (taking one corner if middle cell is taken), the computer automatically fills all 4 corners and not only one as desired.

```
public void takeCorners(){

    if(buttons[1].isEnabled()){
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    }

    else if(buttons[3].isEnabled()){
        buttons[3].setText("O");
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    }

    else if(buttons[7].isEnabled()){
        buttons[7].setText("O");
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    }

    else if (buttons[9].isEnabled()){
        buttons[9].setText("O");
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

I kind of understand why it is doing it as it iterates through the entire if condition but cannot figure out a way around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any more code is necessary let me know even though the question only focus on this bit of code specifically. Thank you

Edit: Code Update.

```
 Button[]   buttons =   new Button[10];
int[] helper = new int[10];
int computer = -10;
int human = 10;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    buttons[1]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.one);
    buttons[2]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.two);
    buttons[3]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.three);
    buttons[4]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.four);
    buttons[5]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.five);
    buttons[6]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.six);
    buttons[7]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.seven);
    buttons[8]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.eight);
    buttons[9]  =   (Button)    findViewById(R.id.nine);

    for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++){
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    clearGrid();
}



public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.one:

            buttons[1].setText("X");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            helper[1] = human;
            break;
        case R.id.two:
            buttons[2].setText("X");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            helper[2] = human;
            break;
        case R.id.three:
            buttons[3].setText("X");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);

            break;
        case R.id.four:
            buttons[4].setText("X");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            helper[4] = human;
            break;
        case R.id.five:
            buttons[5].setText("X");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            helper[5] = human;
            break;
        case R.id.six:
            buttons[6].setText("X");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            helper[6] = human;
            break;
        case R.id.seven:
            buttons[7].setText("X");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            helper[7] = human;
            break;
        case R.id.eight:
            buttons[8].setText("X");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
            helper[8] = human;
            break;
        case R.id.nine:
            buttons[9].setText("X");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
            helper[9]= human;
            break;
    }

    respond();

}

public void clearGrid(){
    for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++){
        buttons[i].setText("");
        buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
}



public void respond(){
    victory();
    avoidLoss();
    takeMiddle();
    takeCorners();
    }
```

Edit: All methods included;

```
public void takeMiddle(){
    if(buttons[5].isEnabled()){
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);

    }
}

public void avoidLoss(){
    if(helper[1] + helper[2] + helper[3] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[1].isEnabled()){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[2].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[3].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //SECOND ROW IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[4] + helper[5] + helper[6] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[4].isEnabled()){
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[6].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    //THIRD ROW IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[7] + helper[8] + helper[9] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[7].isEnabled()){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[8].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[8].setText("O");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[9].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    //FIRST COLUMN IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[1] + helper[4] + helper[7] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[1].isEnabled()){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[4].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[7].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //SECOND COLUMN IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[2] + helper[5] + helper[8] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[2].isEnabled()){
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[8].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[8].setText("O");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //THIRD ROW IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[3] + helper[6] + helper[9] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[3].isEnabled()){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[6].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[9].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //FIRST DIAGONAL

    if(helper[1] + helper[5] + helper[9] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[1].isEnabled()){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[9].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //SECOND DIAGONAL

    if(helper[3] + helper[5] + helper[7] == (2 * human)) {
        if(buttons[3].isEnabled()){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[7].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

public void victory(){
    //FIRST ROW IN THE BOARD
    if(helper[1] + helper[2] + helper[3] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[1].isEnabled()){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[2].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[3].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //SECOND ROW IN THE BOARD
    if(helper[4] + helper[5] + helper[6] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[4].isEnabled()){
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[6].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    //THIRD ROW IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[7] + helper[8] + helper[9] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[7].isEnabled()){
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[8].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[8].setText("O");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[9].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    //FIRST COLUMN IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[1] + helper[4] + helper[7] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[1].isEnabled()){
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);}

    else if (buttons[4].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[4].setText("O");
            buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
        }


    else if(buttons[7].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //SECOND COLUMN IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[2] + helper[5] + helper[8] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[2].isEnabled()){
            buttons[2].setText("O");
            buttons[2].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[8].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[8].setText("O");
            buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //THIRD ROW IN THE BOARD

    if(helper[3] + helper[6] + helper[9] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[3].isEnabled()){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[6].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[9].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //FIRST DIAGONAL

    if(helper[1] + helper[5] + helper[9] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[1].isEnabled()){
            buttons[1].setText("O");
            buttons[1].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[9].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //SECOND DIAGONAL

    if(helper[3] + helper[5] + helper[7] == (2 * computer)) {
        if(buttons[3].isEnabled()){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);}

        else if (buttons[5].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[5].setText("O");
            buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
        }


        else if(buttons[7].isEnabled()) {
            buttons[7].setText("O");
            buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to share more of your code to answer your question. Does takeCorners get called multiple times?

Comment: it could be a problem with .isEnabled(), hard to tell with this.

Comment: I'm guessing you're calling this function several times, perhaps even in a loop - as a single invocation will _not_ take the four corners. Alternatively, there might be a problem with your data structure that causes the corners to appear taken even when they aren't, under some conditions.

Comment: just updated the remaining code, I call the method within other method before closing the OnClick which is sorted with a switch function

Comment: @einpoklum  I only really call it once, I have updated the question with more code to demonstrate it

Comment: @mba12 hope the code added helps answering the question

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro The code you added is not enough to help you debug this. I don't know what is happening inside victory, avoidLoss, & takeMiddle. If you put all the tic-tac-toe logic up we can help you debug. It's also good design to separate the game logic as best you can from the UI code.

Comment: @mba12 Sorry about all this mess up, I'm new to Java so I'm still struggling a bit. I have literally posted all the methods in my code that so far work pretty well apart from what I previously stated. Thanks for the patience and hope it can be sorted

Comment: Your logic looks correct. I would agree with @einpoklum that your method must be getting called more than once. I'd suggesting using System.out.println  method in your takeCorners method just for sanity. Maybe pass it an int and increment the int with each pass. This will either prove or disprove that it's getting called multiple times per button click.

Comment: @rgdayo pardon my ignorance but how could I pass such said int incrementing? thanks

Comment: underneath your human variable, just declare   "int takeCorners = 1;"
Then inside your takeCorners method add:

SystemOut.println("Take Corners Called : " + takeCorners);
takeCorners += 1;